# Is there an R function for loading unprocessed observations into principal components?

Tags: r, pca

I have performed PCA and obtained loadings for components on the training data. Now I would like to apply the loading values for each column for each observation in the testing data so that I have the principal component values for each observation in the testing data based on the loadings obtained from the training data. Is there a function for this or do I need to write it myself?

Comment: There is a higher change to receive constructive feedback, if you provide an example of the data structure you are dealing with and provide a reproducible example. Please also let us know what you have done so far and/or attempted to solve the problem you are facing. From a pure description it is difficult to assess what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your test data is called `test_df`.  then you could do:

```
 scale(test_df, TRUE, FALSE) %*% loadings
```